Beam Splitter acting as unitary time evolution
I have a problem understanding a really important fact about quantum mechanical beam splitters and how to evaluate their action on two incoming modes.
Suppose we have a beam splitter that transforms the two input modes a and b as follows:
$a \rightarrow a^{\prime} = \cos{\frac{\phi}{2}} a + \sin{\frac{\phi}{2}} b$ 
$b \rightarrow b^{\prime} = \cos{\frac{\phi}{2}} b - \sin{\frac{\phi}{2}} a$
This can be treated as a unitary time evolution
$a^{\prime} = U^\dagger a U$ and $b^{\prime} = U^\dagger b U$ generated by the Hamiltonian $H = \hbar(ia^\dagger b - ib^\dagger a)$ so that $U = \exp{(-\frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{\phi}{2}H)}$.
As I understand it, we have two ways of expressing the transformation. We can write a and b inside of a vector and then either write 
$\left(\begin{array}{c} a^\prime \\ b^\prime \end{array}\right) = V \left(\begin{array}{c} a \\ b \end{array}\right)$ where V is just the 2x2 matrix containing the cos and sin terms from above or 
$\left(\begin{array}{c} a^\prime \\ b^\prime \end{array}\right) = U^\dagger \left(\begin{array}{c} a \\ b \end{array}\right)U$ where the U just act on the rows seperately.
We now want to calculate what happens when we insert a Fock state $|1\rangle$ of the first mode and a vacuum state $|0\rangle$ of the second mode, labeling the product state $|1, 0\rangle$.
We do this by simply 'time evolving' the state with U:
$U|1,0\rangle = Ua^\dagger |0,0\rangle = Ua^\dagger U^\dagger U |0,0\rangle = Ua^\dagger U^\dagger|0,0\rangle$ 
Until here I understand everything. However, my lecture notes then say that the action of $U$ from the left and $U^\dagger$ from the right will be equal to the inverse of V acting on the transformed modes, i.e. we get the result:
$... = (\cos{\frac{\phi}{2}}a^{\prime \dagger} - \sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}b^{\prime \dagger})|0,0\rangle = cos{\frac{\phi}{2}} |1^\prime, 0^\prime\rangle - \sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}|0^\prime, 1^\prime\rangle$.
The primed numbers are now Fock state of the new modes after the beam splitter.
Can somebody explain to me why this should be the case? I see that instead of time evolving with U, we evolve with its hermitian conjugate. But we still evolve the mode before the time evolution, not after. Is there an easy way to see why this should be true from the definition of U, V and the relationship between the modes before and after the beam splitter?
Edit: To explain my confusion, my calculation is the following.
We have 
$V \left(\begin{array}{c} a \\ b \end{array}\right) = U^\dagger \left(\begin{array}{c} a \\ b \end{array}\right)U$
Applying $V^{-1}$ as well as $U$ from the left and $U^{\dagger}$ from the right gives 
$U \left(\begin{array}{c} a \\ b \end{array}\right)U^\dagger = V^{-1} \left(\begin{array}{c} a \\ b \end{array}\right) $
which is not what we want to have because $V^{-1}$ is being applied to the non transformed mode operators!
